# Implementing Loop for a Temperature Report query

Tags: java, for-loop

The task is computing the temperature of a warm object after it has been put in a freezer. Assume that the freezer temperature is constant at -20 degrees. Once the object is in the freezer, its temperature drops by (K * dt) degrees in each second, where K=0.001 and dt is the difference between the current object temperature and the freezer temperature. I did the main task which was to compute the temperature of the object (with given initial temperature) after it has been in the freezer for a certain number of seconds. The second task asks me to Implement:

```
public static void temperatureReport(double initialTemperature)
```

The method should print the temperature of an object (with a given initial temperature) after is has been in the freezer for 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 and 60 minutes.
The solution must use a loop. In each iteration of the loop, it must print the number of minutes passed and the current temperature of the object.
The output should be in a tabular format with columns aligned either left or right. The temperature values should be displayed with exactly one digit after the decimal point. Here is the full code I have:

```
package Homework;

    public class Cooling {

        public static final double FREEZER_TEMPERATURE = -20;
        public static final double K = 0.001;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            temperatureTest(70, 0);
            temperatureTest(70, 60); 
            temperatureReport(70);
            timeToCoolTest(70, -10);
            timeToCoolTest(70, -20);
        }




        public static double temperature(double initialTemperature, int seconds) {
            double currentTemp = initialTemperature;
            for (int time = 1; time <= seconds; time++) {
                currentTemp -= K * (currentTemp - FREEZER_TEMPERATURE);
                System.out.printf("After %d seconds, the temperature of the object is %f%n", time, currentTemp);
            }
            return currentTemp;
        }


        // TODO: Implement method as specified in assignment brief 

        public static void temperatureReport(double initialTemperature) {
            double currentTemp = initialTemperature;





        }

        // TODO: Implement method as specified in assignment brief 

        public static int timeToCool(double initialTemperature, double targetTemperature) {
         return 0; }


        public static void timeToCoolTest(double initialTemperature, double targetTemperature) {
            System.out.println("### Time To Cool");
            System.out.println("Initial temperature = " + initialTemperature);
            System.out.println("Target temperature = " + targetTemperature);
            int timeTaken = timeToCool(initialTemperature, targetTemperature);
            System.out.println("Time to cool = " + timeTaken + " seconds\n");
        }

        public static void temperatureTest(double initialTemperature, int seconds) {
            System.out.println("### Temperature Test");
            System.out.println("Initial temperature = " + initialTemperature);
            System.out.println("Seconds = " + seconds);
            double temp = temperature(initialTemperature, seconds);
            System.out.println("Temperature = " + temp + "\n");
        }

    }
```

Could someone give me an idea of what to do to implement the Temperature Report method please? Thank you so much :).

Comment: You can increase the loop counter by 10 and use the loop counter to call the `temperature` function. Snippet: `for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= 60; i+=10) temperature(initialTemperature, i);` Then you just have to work with the result and construct the desired output.

Comment: @puelo ohh thank you so much, how would that look inside the method?

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my code as an answer since the comment section isn't suitable for that. It would look something like this:

```
public static void temperatureReport(double initialTemperature) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= 60; i+=10) {
        double currentTemp = Cooling.temperature(initialTemperature, i);
        System.out.printf("After %d minutes, the temperature of the object is %f%n", i, currentTemp);
        // TODO: Make the output like it has to be.
    }
}
```

Now that obviously does not format the output like you need it. That is something i leave up to u, since this seems to be some kind of assignment/homework.

Comment: Thank you for that mate,  just one more question, should I multiply the time by 60 because it is minutes and I used the code before for seconds. I posted and answer showing the modified code that you gave me slightly.

Comment: Yes. If you need minutes you obviously need to multiply the seconds by 60.

Comment: so regardless of the fact that they are at 10 minute intervals ? Thank you :).

Comment: This is just 10 units, Java does not care if those are 10 seconds or 10 minutes. You could aswell do this: `for(int i = 0; i <= 3600; i+=600)` Thus just increase by 600 every iteration (=600 seconds = 10 minutes)

Comment: ohhh that makes it mor clear, obviously if I use the 3600 one I don't need to multiply by 60. Thank you much for your time mate :).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double temperatureReport(double initialTemperature) {
        double currentTemp = initialTemperature;
           for(int time = 0; time <= 60; time+=10) {
                currentTemp -= (time*60) *(K * (currentTemp - FREEZER_TEMPERATURE));
                System.out.printf("After %d minutes, the temperature of the object is %f%n", time, currentTemp);


            }
        return currentTemp;
        }
```